# int icon meaning in C++ (Visual Studio)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have been working with Visual studio for few months, I just can't understand what this icon means with `int` in C++ . In C# `int` has icon of `struct` , but in C++ I cant understand. Here is icon

[image]

Comment: The closest doc link I can find is here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y47ychfe(v=vs.110).aspx) but your icon does not appear. I've no idea what it means. Perhaps it's the icon for everything that does not fit in any other category!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems to be the icon for *keywords*.

It doesn't appear in David's list because the Object Browser doesn't include keywords.  Intellisense does.